# How to permanently delete Catalina Music.app library without it automatically being brought back from backup?

Tags: catalina, music, apple-music, music.app

I recently upgraded to Catalina on my iMac and Macbook. Everything went smoothly.

I used to manage my music in iTunes on the macbook, but I do not travel as often now, and moved it over to the iMac.

I wanted to play music from the macbook with media sharing and noticed that the library on the macbook is still full of songs that it does not have the files for.

In the past this would have been a simple task fo deleting the library files and restarting iTunes.

Now, with Apple's Music.app, after deleting the library, when I do this is instantly restores the library even when offline.

The questions is: How to permanently delete Catalina Music.app library without it automatically being brought back from backup?

Comment: Does it come back from a (local) backup or is it Apple Music repopulating the library (without downloading unless you play the music locally)?

Comment: What I think is happening is that Catalina keeps a backup and when it finds it misses automatically replaces it. i.e. Quit Music.App. Delete Music folder. Open Music.app which is initially blank and within seconds is populated with records from library. The library is about 87MB and it always brings it back.

Comment: Do you have Apple Music (the cloud service) and is it activated on your laptop?

Comment: No I do not. I also have wi-fi turned off. I found someone else with the same issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1494638/how-to-reset-macos-catalina-muisc-library